# Impedance discontinuity problem at transmission line?

Tags: electromagnetism, transmission-line, rise-time

[image: pic]

I am confused about how the waveform will be to the left of discontinuity. Please help me understand it better.

Here is my understanding:

When the unit step hits the inductive discontinuity, at the discontinuity there is peaking to twice the magnitude of the incident unit step followed up by exponential decay down to input unit step value.

My doubt is :

However i don't understand how the **rise time** is affected and what happens to the waveform which is reflected off the discontinuity !!

Comment: Good question. Do you have a reference or particular book you're looking at?

Comment: I doubt this question has some connection with time domain reflectometry (TDR) where relections off the discontinuites are measured to check for fault location..

Comment: Isn't TDR looking at impulse response? Either way, there is a discontinuity. My guess is you'd see an attenuated unit step left of discontinuity. Please update if you find answer.

Comment: sure i will update